# Pandas Formatting: selectively indent cells in some rows

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

Is there a way to format certain cells within a column using pandas? The only formatting I have been able to find is align the entire column but I would like to have certain rows indented and others fully left aligned (example below). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Category         Value
Total Revenue    2.00
  Widget 1       1.00
  Widget 2       1.00
Total Expenses   2.00
  Widget 1       1.00
  Widget 2       1.00
```

Comment: You could try a hack like `df['Category'].map(lambda x: '    ' + x if x in rows_to_indent else x)`...

Comment: One crude-but-effective approach is to put the leading whitespace in the dataframe column names: `'Total Revenue', ' Widget 1' ...`. (And if you ever need to process the column names, you could `.strip()` them.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add a tab in the strings named Widget, I would go for something like:

-'*df*' is your dataframe

-'*df['Category']*' is the column you want to replace for a new one with the tabulated strings

-Creating a new column

`new_col = ["".join(["\t",i]) if ("Widget" in i) else i for i in df['Category']]`

-Now replacing old column with new column

`df['Category']= new_col`

If you don't want to see the tabulation, you can use spaces("  ") instead of tabulation ("\t"). So:

`new_col = ["".join(["  ",i]) if ("Widget" in i) else i for i in df['Category']]`

`df['Category']= new_col`

Hope it helps.